# Web Content Portlet data not imported from Liferay Lar file

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have created a liferay portal website with web content portlets on each page and each page having theme.

I am able to export the lar file successfully but when I am importing it on another system, I get an error if I import the file without changing any options. It says that transfer has failed. And if I uncheck all applications and uncheck all COntent before importing, the lar file is successfully imported but while running it, only the theme is displayed and data from web content portlets is not present. THis I think is because I had unchecked web content portlet option in both Content and Applications. But without unchecking all these options,the transfer fails everytime.

What should be done?

Comment: Are the version of both liferay same ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is fine to overwrite in target environment, then choose select box "Delete portlet data before Importing". That will delete existed data and imports new data.

> Note: Take backup of database before trying above solution.